# Swift: How to Load JSON in different Table View

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

Hi everybody I'm new to Swift and I need help.

So I have three different JSON that will show in different moments, The first JSON has been loading perfectly, but when I clicking on the item to reload another JSON and show the detail nothing appears.

I'm confused about details:

Need I have three differents table Views for each JSON? or the only one is enough?
When I working with data (JSON) need I use a specific function to prepare the new JSON that will appear as "prepare"?

In my project I have:
Two view controllers: ViewController(default) and DetailViewController.
In my Main.Storyboard: Tab Bar Controller --> Navigation --> Table View

The code of the first View controller:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    var categories = [Category]()
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        let urlString = "https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/categories.php"
        
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
                parse(json: data)
            } else {
                print("error connecting")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func parse(json: Data) {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        print("parse called")
        
        do {
            let jsonCategories = try decoder.decode(Categories.self, from: json)
            
            categories = jsonCategories.categories
            
            tableView.reloadData()
            
        } catch {
            print("error parsin: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return categories.count
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        let category = categories[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = category.idCategory
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = category.strCategoryDescription
        return cell
    }
    
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let newViewController = DetailViewController()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true)
    }
}


The code of the second view controller:

import UIKit
import WebKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
    var webView: WKWebView!
    var meals = [Meal]()

    override func loadView() {
       webView = WKWebView()
        view = webView
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let urlString = "https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?c=Beef"
        
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
                parse(json: data)
            } else {
                print("error connecting")
            }
        }
    }
    func parse(json: Data) {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        print("parse called")
        
        do {
            let jsonMeals = try decoder.decode(Meals.self, from: json)
            
            meals = jsonMeals.meals
            print(String(format:"read %d meals", meals.count))
            
            
            
        } catch {
            print("error parsin: \(error)")
        }
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return meals.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        let meal = meals[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = meal.idMeal
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = meal.strMeal
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Your second view controller doesn't have a table view so it's unclear how this is supposed to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `parse(json: Data)` on DetailViewController does not call `tableView.reloadData()` so the new data cannot be loaded to UITableView

> Need I have three differents table Views for each JSON? or the only one is enough?

If you're loading different JSON files but want to show in the same view. You only need 1 UITableViewCell.

When you load & decode JSON, consider moving it to background queue to avoid blocking main thread.

Comment: Thank you so much I added the tableView.reloadData() and I have this Compiler Error: Reference to member 'reloadData' cannot be resolved without a contextual type

Comment: because `DetailViewController` is a different UIViewController so you need to create `tableView` instance for it, like `ViewController`.